# kubuntu shutdown/restart /closing wallpaper vanishing

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, desktop-background, restart

when I log on, or I close my session or when I lock it, it works, I see wallpaper image in background.
When I decide to turn off, or restart, I see the shutodnw/restart icon, the message and the countdown, on the "gray" central piece of screen, but not the usual image in the background... wallpaper vanish... it is all white in background.
After if I click yes, all white and after I see the usual "boot splash" untill it close or reboot

I had this problem with kubuntu 16.04, I moved today to 16.10 but it's the same...

No idea how to solve it...

sorry for my bad/wrong english

Comment: please rephrase your question. use less repetitive punctuation but state clearly what you did, where you did it, what the outcome was and what you did expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry for my English,
when I Click on "K" menu with gear, and I choose exit option, and after in the exit menu I click on reboot or shutdown, usually it appears the desktop with wallpaper, icons and so on, with on top in the middle of the screen a gray strip with reboot/shutdown icon a message about reboot or shutdown, the countdown and two buttons... cancel or reboot/shutdown, is it clear till now?.

On my linux box, it doesn't happens, the wallpaper and icons disapper, it's all white with the usual grey strip described before.

When I click ok to reboot/shutdown,the screen is all white until it starts boot splash with black  screen and kubuntu in the middle and it shutdown or reboot.

It doesn't happens when I log on or when I suspesnd or I disconnect., only with reboot and shutdown

I tryed, to delete and re-install all kde, maybe some conf file is broken (but I amnot an expert)

ctrl+alt+f1
log in as root
systemctl stop sddm
apt-get purge kubuntu desktop
apt-get purge *kde
apt-get purge  kde*

apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
apt-get install kubuntu-desktkop

reboot

nothing changed... it is all equals as before